# c++ int array - removing an int and shifting the rest of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am hoping a fresh set of eyes can help me find what I am doing wrong. I am trying to search an array for a certain int and once it finds it, it will delete it and shift the remaining elements over to fill in where the "deletion" is.

This would be used on a class obj like A.remove(25) where the obj A contains some vars such as Num (the number of elements in the array), Cap (total capacity of the array), and Pool[] (which contains all of the numbers).

```
bool Set::remove(int X)
{
        for(unsigned J=0; J<Num; J++)
        {
                if(Pool[J] == X)
                {
                        for(unsigned Z=J; J<Num; Z++)
                        {
                                if(Z == (Num-1))
                                {
                                        Pool[Z] = NULL;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        Pool[Z] = Pool[Z+1];
                                }
                        }
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your inner for loop:

```
for(unsigned Z=J; J<Num; Z++)
```

The loop condition should be `Z<Num` instead of `J<Num`:

```
for(unsigned Z=J; Z<Num; Z++)
```

Otherwise `J<Num` will keep evaluating to true and `Z` will be incremented until it's out of bounds of `Pool`

Comment: @icepack, @SethCarnegie: No, actually I did not =) You'll possibly need to change the font on your browser to notice the difference between `J` and `Z` - they do look pretty similar when they are in uppercase (Check the history on my answer and you'll see I had it right from the start)

Comment: How would I get it to stop adding a zero on to the end of the array, do I need to get rid of that NULL statement?

Comment: @sharkman It's a bit complicated: right now the NULL statement is acting as a sentinel / flag value for the "end" of your array, I would fix this by decrementing `Num` by 1 right before you `return true` in the if statement, and keep using `Num` as the counter variable to keep track of how many values are actually valid counting sequentially from the first index in `Pool`. The underlying problem is that resizing an array dynamically is messy since it's contiguous in memory. You can look into realloc: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/, but I'm really no expert there.